# Limiting the resources used by a process

Tags: linux, performance, resources, ramdisk

This is now the third time I've had this problem and had to look up how to do it with the specific caveats of my particular instance. As such I want to write a script that will go through all the steps for me and work for most instances.

My current use-case is running AFL on a laptop. As it says:

> - Your CPU will run hot and will need adequate cooling. In most cases, if
>   cooling is insufficient or stops working properly, CPU speeds will be
>   automatically throttled. That said, especially when fuzzing on less
>   suitable hardware (laptops, smartphones, etc), it's not entirely impossible
>   for something to blow up.
> - Targeted programs may end up erratically grabbing gigabytes of memory or
>   filling up disk space with junk files. AFL tries to enforce basic memory
>   limits, but can't prevent each and every possible mishap. The bottom line
>   is that you shouldn't be fuzzing on systems where the prospect of data loss
>   is not an acceptable risk.
> - Fuzzing involves billions of reads and writes to the filesystem. On modern
>   systems, this will be usually heavily cached, resulting in fairly modest
>   "physical" I/O - but there are many factors that may alter this equation.
>   It is your responsibility to monitor for potential trouble; with very heavy
>   I/O, the lifespan of many HDDs and SSDs may be reduced.

As such I was going to run it on a ramdisk (had to look up how to do that again) with a low priority (nice -10 or nice 10, I can never remember) and do some additional limiting (with cpu_limit I suppose).

I've wanted to do these kinds of things before, with additional goals of limiting disk usage in total and reducing network I/O speeds.

My goal is to have a simple script that I can run like:

```
./pretend_its_on_a_slow_computer_so_my_computer_doesnt_lag.sh my_program with its arguments
```

This script should at least do the following:

- Limit CPU usage
- Limit disk I/O for SSD/HDD longevity
- Limit network I/O
- Limit disk usage
- Limit memory usage
- Limit anything else you can think of that could damage my computer :)

So far I've come up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /mnt/temp_ramdisk

mount -t tmpfs -o size=2g tmpfs /mnt/temp_ramdisk

cp -r . /mnt/temp_ramdisk

cd /mnt/temp_ramdisk

# Assumes trickle is installed to limit network i/o
nice 19 trickle "$@"

cp -r /mnt/temp_ramdisk .

umount /mnt/temp_ramdisk

rm -r /mnt/temp_ramdisk
```

However this is fairly clunky (though I can't think of a better way to get local files into the ramdisk) and lacks hard limits on writing outside of the ramdisk or using too much memory or heating up the CPU too much. I also think I could do something with cgroups to improve things, but I'm not well enough versed in them.

How can I improve this to achieve what I want?

Comment: Wouldn't running it inside a VM give you more control over resources?

Comment: possibly, but unless I can get a VM to run entirely in RAM it wouldn't solve the disk I/O wear issue. Plus getting the local files into the VM could be quite time consuming.

Comment: In `qemu` you can attach just about anything to a vm as a "disk" ... so your ramdisk solution might be okay... or just copy a qcow2 image to a `tmpfs`...make sure you have enough physical ram for the host plus the vm's disk AND memory... and make sure you don't swap.

Comment: you could take a look at cgroups for various resources limitations. But cgroups v2 is required to handle properly disk I/O limitation along disk cache. https://andrestc.com/post/cgroups-io/ . The network part also involves tc the traffic controller/scheduler. I don't think trickle (library wrapper) should be allowed to interact with a fuzzer.